# Get IEnumerable from LINQ select

Tags: c#, linq, dbcontext

We have a LINQ select from a DB context like this:

```
public Category GetCategory(int categoryId)
{
    Category result = null;
    using (var db = new MyContext())
    {
        result = (from entry in db.Categories
                  where entry.CategoryId == categoryId
                  select entry).FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return result;
}
```

We are afraid that this will work from time-to-time because the function returns `IQueryable` and the garbage collector will kill the `db` (`Using` ends in this function).

How can we keep the `Using` in this function and return the selected object but disconnected from `db`?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with the code you've posted?

Comment: certain methods will execute the IQueryable, such as ToList or FirstOrDefault(as in your example)  once this occurs, the object is stored in memory and you can safely dispose of the context.  this method seems correct.

Comment: Hovering over FirstOrDefault(), I still see that the object is IQueryable. Is VS 2012 wrong?

Comment: @Miro The `FirstOrDefault()` function is being performed *on* an `IQueryable`, the return value of it is not itself an `IQueryable`.

Comment: The function signature is `T FirstOrDefault( this IQueryable<T> q )`, note return type of `T`

Comment: `T` in this case is the `Category` class.  It's returning a plain old CLR object, not an IQueryable.  It's an extension method which is performed on an IQueryable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What function returns `IQueryable<T>`?  Your code does not return an `IQueryable<T>`, it returns null or an instance of `Category` - the results of the `.FirstOrDefault()` call.  The instance of `Category` will work just fine after your `DbContext` is disposed.

Perhaps your question relates to lazy loading of navigation properties?  That would bomb outside of the `using` block.  You should disable lazy loading and/or proxy generation to avoid this or explicitly load navigation properties/collections prior to exiting the `using` block

Comment: I guess the VS confused me because hovering on top shows IQueryable. Thanks!